# Comparing two lists and getting higher values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
class Order
{
    public int Shares { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

and two lists:

```
List<Order> _buyOrder = new List<Order>();
List<Order> _sellOrder = new List<Order>();
```

Now I need to use LINQ to create a new list where all values of _buyOrder.price is higher then the _sellOrder.price. Without LINQ I'm doing two for loop which is ugly and annoying. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

I have tried without success:

```
var t = _buyOrder
    .Select(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Price > _sellOrder.Select(y=>y)
    .Where(y=>y.Price));
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Post your loop code also to make us understand your goal

Comment: I described pretty clearly what I want to achieve: Create a new list where all the values of the price property of the _buyOrder list is higher then the price property of the _sellOrder list.

Comment: @Dimo, do Shares need to be equal, or you need every buyprice higher then maximum sellprice?

Comment: @Dimo you are not clear, _sellOrder is a list and it has lots of prices, it does not have a price property. Do you mean max(price) in _sellOrder?

Comment: Do you need a pairwise comparison of elements from _buy and _sell? Do you want a list of those _buy elements that are more expensive than their counterpart in _sell, or do you just want a new price-list with higher prices than all previous prices? No, your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var sellMax = _sellOrder.Max(y => y.Price);
var t = _buyOrder.Where(x => x.Price > sellMax);
```

Comment: Am not sure whether this is what OP mean, I edited for performance

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm not sure either, but I answered based on what I had known. If this is not what he wants, I will gladly edit my answer.  Thank you for edit, by the way.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If you think that I deserve it ... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = _sellOrder.Max(x => x.Price);
var result =    from b in _buyOrder
                where b.Price > max
                select b;
```